# Анимация броуновского движения

Tags: java, android, анимация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать анимацию броуновского движения? 
Объект должен двигаться по экрану меняя финальные координаты при достижении, например, границы активности. 
В идеале в пределах активности/фрагмента, но можно и с разлетом за предел.
Из мыслей только динамически задавать новые координаты при достижении текущих, но эта идея не нравится.

Comment: Как вы отрисовывать-то хотите? Если через Surface view, то можно создать необходимое количество объектов и рассчитывать для них скорости, которые будут инвертироваться при достижении краев экрана. Для не самых древних девайсов сотни объектов хорошо и плавно работают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я полагаю ТС интересует не техника, а математика - как моделировать.

Делается это так:

1. Задаем начальные координаты частицы `{X0, Y0}`
2. Далее для каждой координаты задаем случайную вероятность, скажем `{Px, Py}` (P - вероятность от 0 до 1)
3. Вычисляем смещение вдоль каждой координаты через инверсную [функцию вероятностей Гаусса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) `X1=X0+InvGauss(Px), Y1=Y0+InvGauss(Py)`
4. Далее по циклу вычисляем на основе `{x1, y1}` уже `{x2, y2}` и.т.д.

Физический смысл состоит в том, что частица в ходе броуновского движения испытывает множественные случайные столкновения, которые как раз и описываются распределением вероятности Гаусса т.н. *шапкой Гаусса*

Вычисление инверсной функции Гаусса (то есть вычисление из вероятности величины отклонения) можно [найти здесь](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/22library/Gaussian.java.html)

Величину прыжков частицы можно регулировать параметром `sigma` - среднеквадратичным отклонением.

Также в помощь [симуляция броуновского движения на Excel](https://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/StochasticProcess/BrownianMotion/BrownianMotionSimulation.html)